# Custom ArrayAdapter: why do I get a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, gallery, adapter, android-arrayadapter, android-gallery

Sorry for bothering people so proficient, but I am new to Android and I am trying to learn...

Anyway, I am trying to build a Gallery with a custom adapter.

But I get NullPointerException as soon as the program tries to invoke the adapter.

Any help very much appreciated!!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Gallery gal;
    private List<Elementi> el;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        List<Elementi> el = new ArrayList<Elementi>();
        int[] tabDrawables = new int[] {
                     R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.    img5,R.drawable.img6,R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10};

        String[] descrizione =    {"cani","boffo","gigo","belo","fyyfy","bogin","boginetti","zippe","ninne","cestino","cagnin    o","cucciolo",};

        for (int numero =1; numero <= 10;numero++) {

            ImageView imgm = new ImageView(this);
            imgm.setImageResource(tabDrawables[numero]);
            el.add(new Elementi(imgm,descrizione[numero]));

        };


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Gallery gal=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.galleria);
        gal.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());


    }
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Elementi> {
    public MyAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, el);
    }   
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                View row= convertView;  
                TextView txt =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.testorow);
                txt.setText(el.get(position).tx) ;
                ImageView ima =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.immagine);
                ima.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Inte    ger.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                return row;};

}    


public class Elementi { 
public ImageView im;
public String tx; 
public Elementi(ImageView img,String txt){
        ImageView im =img;
        String tx = txt;        

    }

}

}
```

My LogCat:

```
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gallery/com.example.gallery.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:114)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.example.gallery.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  ... 11 more
11-29 20:26:28.547: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 17% free 2496K/3000K, paused 13ms+24ms, total 191ms
```

Comment: No problem about asking too much, but please post your logcat.

Comment: What line gives the NPE? Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: I updated my answer for your LogCat, you accidentally created _two_ copies of `el`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `if(convertView == null)` and when it is you need to inflate a new View, or you can let the super class handle this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ...
}
```

The presentations: [Turbo Charge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) or [World of ListView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) by lead Android programmers will help you understand how to work with `getView()` without slowing down your app.

---

**Addition**
From your LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
```

This means the list you passed to the ArrayAdapter is `null`...

This is because you have *two* different copies of `el`:

```
private List<Elementi> el; // This one is null and is what's passed to your adapter
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<Elementi> el = new ArrayList<Elementi>(); // This one only exists in onCreate!
```

I don't really like how Java let's you do this without a warning... Simply change the last line to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    el = new ArrayList<Elementi>();
```

(However you will hit another NullPointerException if you don't address `getView()` as stated above.)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the logcat, I think here's your mistake. The `convertView` parameter of the `getView()` method is null the very first time the method is called. Your job is to inflate a view when `convertView == null`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
   View row= convertView;  
   if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, parent, false);    
   }

   TextView txt =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.testorow);
   //(...) more code
}
```

When `getView()` is called again, it uses this `View` as a `convertView`, and so `convertView` will probably not be `null`.

Comment: Thanks, but inflate asks for two arguments (Int,ViewGroup)

Comment: Thank you, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your Custom Adapter's `getView()` `View row` is `null`.

So this code line `txt.setText(el.get(position).tx);` gives you `NullPointerException`.

Actually you have to check for `convertView` whether it is `NULL` or **NOT**.

If  `convertView` is `NULL` then you have to inflate the XML Layout again.

Something like,

```
View row = convertView;  
if(row == null)
{
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but inflate asks for two arguments (Int,ViewGroup)