# ListView - findviewbyid returns null

Tags: android, listview

I know that there are a lot of questions like this, but every answer is like: you are missing setContentView().

That's my java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pending_invoice);

    invoices = new PendingInvoices().getListInvoices();
    fillList();
}

private void fillList() {
    ListAdapter dataAdapter = new PendingInvoiceAdapter(this, R.layout.pending_invoice_row, invoices);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.invoice_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Everytime it stops with `NullPointerException` on `listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`.

As you can see, I have `setContentView()` on `onCreate` method.

My activity_pending_invoice has ListView with name `invoice_list_view`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/invoice_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

pending_invoice_row is just a `LinearLayout` with one `Textview`

Does anybody know what's wrong? It's like a nightmare!

Comment: Have you ever checked your dataAdapter?

Comment: @tdmsoares What do you mean? If dataAdapter is not null? I split the error line while debugging (with `(dataAdapter);` on second line) and the error message always appears on `listView.setAdapter`

Comment: post the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: This code looks correct. And the `NullPointerException` on setting adapter can only mean, that `ListView` wasn't found. I'd suggest to delete Build folder of the project and Clean Rebuild it(and also remove the old app from Emulator/Phone). P.s. `invoice_list_view`'s root `LinearLayout` can be converted to `FrameLayout`, as has only `ListView` inside

Comment: @Blackbelt thank you for comment. While copying the log message I found the reason why it had not been working.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will have the same problem:

Check the stacktrace, you may found this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 20:26:28.327: E/AndroidRuntime(786): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330).
```

It means that the `List` you are passing to `ListAdapter` is null.

I don't know why android showed the `listView` to be null, but I'm glad it works now :)

---

Thank for comments to my question, it helps a lot. And thanks to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634033/custom-arrayadapter-why-do-i-get-a-nullpointerexception)